# I am able to see only "Execute cell" but not "Debug cell" In my Jupyter Notebook's Scala cell in VS Code. Why?

Tags: scala, visual-studio-code, jupyter

I am trying to debug jupyter scala notebook in visual studio code but I am unable to see debug cell option can any one please here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KGgO.png)